# Aeson Prisms with "free" references

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens, aeson

Just read the brilliant "[Lens/Aeson Traversals/Prisms"](https://www.fpcomplete.com/user/tel/lens-aeson-traversals-prisms) article and have a real-world application. Given the following anonymized JSON structure, how would I prism out a collection rather than a specific value?

```
{"Locations" : [ {"id" : "2o8434", "averageReview": ["5", "1"]},{"id" : "2o8435", "averageReview": ["4", "1"]},{"id" : "2o8436", "averageReview": ["3", "1"]},{"id" : "2o8437", "averageReview": ["2", "1"]},{"id" : "2o8438", "averageReview": ["1", "1"]}]}
```

I have:

```
λ> locations ^? key "Locations" . nth 0 . key "averageReview" . nth 0
Just (String "5")
```

What I want:

```
λ> locations ^? key "Locations" . * . key "averageReview" . nth 0
["5", "4", "3", "2", "1"]
```

Am I missing the entire point of prisms? Or is this a legitimate use case?

Cheers!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want to replace `nth 0` with [`values`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.2/docs/Data-Aeson-Lens.html#v%3avalues) which is a traversal over Aeson arrays.

Also, since you have a traversal with multiple results and want a list rather than a Maybe, you have to use `^..` instead of `^?`.

```
*Main> locations ^.. key "Locations" . values . key "averageReview" . nth 0
[String "5",String "4",String "3",String "2",String "1"]
```

As Carl helpfully pointed out, you can add a `. _String` to the end to just get the strings out directly:

```
*Main> locations ^.. key "Locations" . values . key "averageReview" . nth 0 . _String
["5","4","3","2","1"]
```

Comment: Tack a `. _String` onto the end just to make it an exact match.